# loop over columns in dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to loop over 2 columns in a specific dataframe and I want to access the data by the name of the column but it gives me this error (type error) on line 3

```
i=0
for name,value in df.iteritems():
 
  q1=df[name].quantile(0.25)
  q3=df[name].quantile(0.75)
  IQR=q3-q1
  min=q1-1.5*IQR
  max=q3+1.5*IQR
  minout=df[df[name]<min]
  maxout=df[df[name]>max]
  new_df=df[(df[name]<max) & (df[name]>min)]
  i+=1
  if i==2:
    break
```

Comment: Please add a sample of `df` large enough to reproduce the error. Also please include a sample of what output you hope to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to exclude outliers based on the 1.5*IQR rule. Here is a simpler solution:

Input dummy data:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'col%s' % (i+1): np.random.normal(size=1000)
                   for i in range(4)})
```

[image: input data]

Removing the outliers (keep data: Q1-1.5*IQR < data < Q3+1.5*IQR):

```
Q1 = df.iloc[:, :2].quantile(.25)
Q3 = df.iloc[:, :2].quantile(.75)
IQR = Q3-Q1

non_outliers = (df.iloc[:, :2] > Q1-1.5*IQR) & (df.iloc[:, :2] < Q3+1.5*IQR)

new_df = df[non_outliers.all(axis=1)]
```

output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Type error might happen for a lot of reasons so it will be better if you add part of the DF to try to understand the issue.

Also to loop over columns you can also use the `iterrows()` function:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
    
for _, content in df.iterrows():
    print(content['columnname']) #add the name of the columns you want to loop over
```

refer to the following link for more information

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows